# Add sub-task rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm using rails 4 and I need to add a subtask for seeding our database using demo data (for product demo's). I want to make it a subtask called `rake db:seed:demo`, how can I do this?

I tried to subtask using this code, but I got an error from rake saying task not found.

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

API::Application.load_tasks

task :demo => :seed do

end

task :seed => :db
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `namespace` directive:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do
    task :demo do
    end
  end
end
```